# Applying "while(a[++i] < v )" in R

Tags: c, arrays, r, operator-precedence

The following C code searches an array, a[], from a given left index and from a given right index, for the two indices (i and j) where every array value between the left index and i is less than v, and every array value between j and the right index is greater than v:

```
i= leftindex - 1 ;
j = rightindex ;
while(TRUE) { 
while( a[++i] < v) ;
while( a[--j] > v) ;
if (i >= j ) { break }
... }
```

This construct can be seen in various implementations of the quick sort algorithm.

My question is this:  is the following the most efficient way to accomplish the same thing in the language R when a is a vector?

```
i = leftindex - 1 ;
j = rightindex ;
v = a[rightindex]
while(TRUE) {
  while (a[i <- i+1] < v ) { }  # R doesn't get the ++ operator
  while (a[j <- j-1] > v) { }   # R doesn't get the -- operator
  if (i >= j ) { break }
  ... 
}
```

So, as an example, if 'a' is:

```
 a <- c('a','s','o','r','t','i','n','g','e','x','a','m','p','l','e')
```

... and

```
left.index = 1; right.index = 15
```

... then after this code runs I would expect the values of v, i and j to be:

```
v = e
i = 2
j = 11
```

I can't find anything that defines the operator "++" or "--" in R.

Does precedence in R guarantee the order of calculation of "a[i<-i+1] < v" or did I get lucky with my RStudio implementation?

I was toying with applying an anonymous function (decrement and compare) to the vector a at the appropriate places but this was simpler to write.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect a combination of `which` and `diff` can do it an R vector operation which would be a lot more efficient than `while` loops. Why not put in a data example and your specification of the right answer?

Comment: OK, thanks, I edited the original question to include an example.  Sorry, I had a typo in the code snippet initializing j, so I corrected that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you're trying to replace the following lines with R versions:

```
while( a[++i] < v);
while( a[--j] > v);
```

A simple way to write these two lines would be:

```
i <- i + min(which(a[(i+1):length(a)] >= v))
j <- max(which(a[1:(j-1)] <= v))
```

In each case, the which function is computing all the indices in which some subset of `a` has the appropriate value, so it's likely less efficient than just looping in custom C/C++ code until you find the first such entry.

If efficiency is important to you, you could write a very simple `Rcpp` function for this operation. Here, I've defined `increment` and `decrement` which do the two operations, taking particular care to convert `i` and `j`, which I assume are 1-indexed in the R code, to a 0-indexed value in the C++ code:

```
library(Rcpp)
increment <- cppFunction("
  int increment(NumericVector a, int i, const double v) {
    while( a[(++i)-1] < v) ;
    return i;
  }")

decrement <- cppFunction("
  int decrement(NumericVector a, int j, const double v) {
    while( a[(--j)-1] > v) ;
    return j;
  }")
```

Then you could convert your two lines to `i <- increment(a, i, v)` and `j <- decrement(a, j, v)`.

Comment: Thanks for the Rcpp reference.  I am not aware of that package (very new to the R world) and will look into it.

Comment: I like your answer.  I agree, the min(which(...)) will do more compares than the while(..) which stops on the first element meeting the criteria.  Because compares are the "coin of the realm" when sorting I like the idea of minimizing them.